# can't recognize parameter in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, parameters

When i try to call next function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION client_visits(id INT)
RETURNS 
    TABLE("date_visit" Date, "time_visit" Time, "visit_type" VARCHAR(30)   )
AS $$ BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT schedule.date_visit, schedule.time_visit, schedule.visit_type FROM schedule 
WHERE schedule.id IN (SELECT s.schedule_id FROM schedule_client_visit s WHERE s.client_id = id);
RAISE Notice 'id =%', id; END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There is a message that they dont know what id is, column or parameter. I have tried to write like

```
(SELECT s.schedule_id FROM schedule_client_visit s WHERE s.client_id = _id)
```

with prefix, but its doesnt work.

Comment: if i change that id in subquery on any number and then i would call the function, its working. So problem is 100% in this parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1) keep the name "id" but refer to it using functionName.ArgumentName (so `client_visits.id`)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html

> [36.4.1] If the argument name is the same as any column name in the current
>   SQL command within the function, the column name will take precedence.
>   To override this, qualify the argument name with the name of the
>   function itself, that is function_name.argument_name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION client_visits(id INT)
RETURNS 
    TABLE("date_visit" Date, "time_visit" Time, "visit_type" VARCHAR(30)   )
AS $$ BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT schedule.date_visit, schedule.time_visit, schedule.visit_type FROM schedule 
WHERE schedule.id IN (SELECT s.schedule_id FROM schedule_client_visit s WHERE s.client_id = client_visits.id);
RAISE Notice 'id =%', client_visits.id; END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2) as you tried, used an underscore (or else), but don't forget to rename the argument in the function header as well.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION client_visits(_id INT)
RETURNS 
    TABLE("date_visit" Date, "time_visit" Time, "visit_type" VARCHAR(30)   )
AS $$ BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT schedule.date_visit, schedule.time_visit, schedule.visit_type FROM schedule 
WHERE schedule.id IN (SELECT s.schedule_id FROM schedule_client_visit s WHERE s.client_id = _id);
RAISE Notice 'id =%', _id; END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: 3) Use placeholder: `... WHERE s.client_id = $1`